# Swift: Cast Any Object to Int64 = nil

Tags: swift, int64

i have a question. I was wondering why this is happend?

```
var dict : [String : Any] = ["intValue": 1234, "stringValue" : "some text"]
dict["intValue"] as? Int64  // = nil (why)
dict["intValue"] as? Int    // = 1234
```

can anybody tell me why the cast to Int64 returns nil?

**Edited part:**

I have simplify my question, but i think this was not a good idea. :)

In my special case I will get back a Dictionary from 
a message body of WKScriptMessage.

I know that in one field of the Dictionary there is a Int value that can be 
greater than Int32.

So if I cast this value to Int it will works on 64-bit systems. But what 
happend on 32-bit systems? I think here is a integer overflow or?

Must I check both to support both systems? Something like this:

```
func handleData(dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
  val value: Int64?
  if let int64Value = dict["intValue"] as? Int64 {
    value = int64Value
  } else if let intValue = dict["intValue"] as? Int {
    value = intValue
  }

  //do what ever i want with the value :)
}
```

Comment: can be a nice article [link](http://vluxe.io/numbers-swift.html)

Comment: thanks, that makes something more clear

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In

```
let dict : [String : AnyObject] = ["intValue": 1234, "stringValue" : "some text"]
```

the number `1234` is stored as an `NSNumber` object, and that can
be cast to `Int`, `UInt`, `Float`, ..., but *not* to the fixed
size integer types like `Int64`.

To retrieve a 64-bit value even on 32-bit platforms, you have to
go via `NSNumber` explicitly:

```
if let val = dict["intValue"] as? NSNumber {
    let int64value = val.longLongValue // This is an `Int64`
    print(int64value)
}
```

Comment: In my case cast to `UInt` returning `nil`.  
Thanks for hint with `NSNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You can now directly use **val.int64value** instead of **val.longLongValue**, provided val is a NSNumber